# openpyxl 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'font'

Tags: python, fonts, openpyxl, nonetype

I'm writing a function that puts values into a spreadsheet and colors the cell based on the value. Now for some reason I'm getting a weird 'NoneType' error that's completely stumping me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vix.py", line 168, in <module>
    printexceldaily(1990, 2015, 'All_Lows', 10, 15, 18, 28)
  File "vix.py", line 166, in printexceldaily
    xlbook.save('%s.xlsx' % sheetname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 281, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 214, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 197, in save
    self.write_data(archive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 98, in write_data
    archive.writestr(ARC_STYLE, self.style_writer.write_table())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/styles.py", line 39, in write_table
    self._write_cell_xfs(number_format_node, fonts_node, fills_node, borders_node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/styles.py", line 159, in _write_cell_xfs
    font = st.font
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'font'
```

I tried looking at the code in styles.py and excel.py to see if I could figure out what might be causing it but I can't really make sense of any of it.

Here's my code:

```
def printexceldaily(startyear, endyear, sheetname, start, hold, buy, end):

xlbook = Workbook()
xsheet = xlbook.active
xsheet.title = sheetname
colors = colorlist()
comparisonlist = comparisonmap(start, hold, buy, end)
length = len(comparisonlist)

# fill a list with a style for every element of colors using coloredcell
styles = [coloredcell(color) for color in colors] 

def getstyle(value):
    for ceiling in comparisonlist:
        if value < ceiling: 
            z = np.where(comparisonlist==ceiling)
            return styles[z[0]]
        elif value > comparisonlist[length - 1]: # we need to check if value is greater than upper bound too
            return styles[length - 1]

# create the cells for days
for i in range(2, 32):
    xsheet.cell(row = 1, column = i).value = i

xlrow = endyear - startyear + 2
for year in range(startyear, endyear):
    for month in range(12):
        xsheet.cell(row = xlrow, column = 1).value = "%s, %d" % (xltomonth[month+1], year)
        for day in range(monthlim[month + 1]):
            curdatestr = '%d-%d-%d' % (year, month + 1, day + 1)
            try:
                curx = vix.loc[curdatestr, 'Low']
            except KeyError:
                xsheet.cell(row = xlrow, column = day+2).value = np.nan
            else:
                xsheet.cell(row = xlrow, column = day+2).value = curx #add value to cell
                xsheet.cell(row = xlrow, column = day+2).style = getstyle(curx) #add style to cell

        xlrow += 1
print('saving')
xlbook.save('%s.xlsx' % sheetname)
```

I've gotten a very similar "printexcelmonthly()" function working that I can post if it would be helpful but for some reason this one keeps bugging out when I try to save the spreadsheet o_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incomplete or badly formatted: where is the body of the function `printexceldaily`? What version of openpyxl are you using?

I suspect the problem is related to the styles you're creating. These must be instances of `openpyxl.styles.Style` objects which will always have `font` attributes. If you want to debug this you can look at the contents of `xlbook.shared_styles`.

Comment: all the code below the constructor is the body; I'm not sure why I can't get the indentation to show properly on here, but I posted the whole file on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ZSYSm8LT). I suspected the problem might have been not creating a font but I copied the default "font" property from the openpyxl documentation into the styles I created and still got the same error. The printexcelsheet function uses the same styles&colors yet works correctly, even when I don't specify the font.
I'm not sure how to check my openpyxl version but running pip3 with --upgrade says it's up to date

Comment: I looked at xlbook.shared_styles and surely enough it contains the 32 styles I've created followed by a single `None` at the end. I'm not sure how it got there though :/ I should add that this is the first Python program I've written and I don't really have a solid idea of what I'm doing, just trying to feel my way through it. Is something I'm doing causing the 33rd element to appear?

Comment: Try deleting that stray style. `del xlbook.shared_styles[32]`

Comment: It completely inexplicably stopped adding the extra 'None' to the shared_styles list and is now working correctly, possibly because of restarting my VM? o.O Hopefully it stays this way but I wish I knew how it was getting added in the first place

Comment: The cause of the error is that your lookup function can return `None` because neither of the conditions is met. In Python the default return for any function is `None`.

Comment: You can check this by invoking the debugger `if getstyle(curx) is None` which for me happens for `xlrow == 157 and day == 9`

You could, of course, set a condition when this is the case not to set a style.